# Dart - How to check if Git is correctly installed?

Tags: git, dart

So I'm using Tortoise Git, and I'm trying to install the json_object package from git. When running pub install I get this error:

> Cannot install 'json_object' from Git
>   (git://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject.git). Please ensure Git
>   is correctly installed.

How can I make sure Git is installed correctly? I'm using Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: Do you have the `bin` folder in your environment path? The `bin` folder is located within the Git installation directory. You can google for "how to modify environment path" if you need help on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to [issue 4947](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4947)

> Run pub from Windows shell with git installed and available in `PATH`:

```
D:\Tools\dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub install                                                                                
Cannot install 'dartlib' from Git (git://github.com/kevmoo/dartlib.git).                                                                        
Please ensure Git is correctly installed.     
git --version                                                                                                         
git version 1.7.7.1.msysgit.0
```

> Seems, that this issue related to [Issue 1705](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1705) as git is available as `git.cmd`.
>
> Replacing "`git`" to "`git.cmd`" at `pub`'s sources (`io.dart` and `git_source.dart`) fixes `pub` for my environment.